# Trailing spaces when authenticating to WSO2 Identity Server

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have found that my users are sometimes entering a trailing space after their username.  This happens most often when copy & pasting their user name from an email or other electronic document.

What happens is that the server will trim that space when authenticating that user, which then succeeds, but will not trim that space with retrieving claim values, which then fails.

The result is that the user is passed to the service provider and then the service provider reports they do not exist.

Is there a way to trim those spaces so that both the authentication and claims processes work?

WSO2 Identity Server 5.1.0

Thanks,
pat

Comment: I use AD for my Identity Store.

Comment: Can You report a bug on this, We will fix this in future releases? JiRA : https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY

Comment: I had the same problem and filed the bug/feature request in the wso2 jira.
https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-5864 Currently it's scheduled for 5.3.1-GA Cheers Mat