# WSO2 Identity Server 5.3.0 user store: List users and login works, but claim manager won't find user

Tags: active-directory, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I've installed WSO2 Identity Server 5.3.0 and configured it with an Active Directory as primary user store. 
Everything worked fine and there were no issues until now. Now it behaves super strange.

I can list all users easily in the IS. I can edit their profile data. I can also use SAML to login from other applications.
If I login with a user through SAML, the user is authenticated and then I get the following error in the IS:

```
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.claims.impl.DefaultClaimHandler} -  Error occurred while retrieving http://wso2.org/claims/emailaddress claim value for user user@domain.com
org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: UserNotFound: User user@domain.com does not exist in: PRIMARY
WARN {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.claims.impl.DefaultClaimHandler} -  Subject claim could not be found amongst unfiltered local claims
DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.claims.impl.DefaultClaimHandler} -  Returning claims from claim handler = []
DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.claims.impl.DefaultClaimHandler} -  UNFILTERED_IDP_CLAIM_VALUES map property set to []
DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.claims.impl.DefaultClaimHandler} -  UNFILTERED_LOCAL_CLAIM_VALUES map property set to []
DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.claims.impl.DefaultClaimHandler} -  UNFILTERED_SP_CLAIM_VALUES map property set to []
WARN {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.sequence.impl.DefaultStepBasedSequenceHandler} -  Subject claim could not be found. Defaulting to Name Identifier.
```

The login goes through as normal, but all the attributes I need in the SAML response are missing. (A day ago this still worked)

Does anyone know where I could start to fix this?
I had a look at the claim mappings, and couldn't find anything that looks wrong. Is it possible to reset the claim mappings to default?

I also deleted and recreated the service providers and it didn't help.

I checked the user-mgt.xml (especially the UserNameSearchFilter) and everything seems to work fine (otherwise it would not display all the users in IS).

**UPDATE:**

Some new information:
So I used a second WSO2 IS to check if the problem is in the IS or the AD. The second IS has no problem getting the claims during Login.

So it has to be a configuration related issue.

**UPDATE 2:**

So I played around with log levels and found the following:

```
DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Searching for user user@domain.com
DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Searching for user with SearchFilter: (&(objectClass=user)(mail=user@domain.com )) in SearchBase: 

DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Name in space for user@domain.com  is null
DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  User: user@domain.com  exist: false
DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Searching for user user@domain.com
DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Searching for user with SearchFilter: (&(objectClass=user)(mail=user@domain.com )) in SearchBase: 

DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Name in space for user@domain.com  is null
DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  User: user@domain.com  exist: false
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.claims.impl.DefaultClaimHandler} -  Error occurred while retrieving http://wso2.org/claims/emailaddress claim value for user user@domain.com
```

Could the trailing whitespace in the Search Filter be a problem? (and where does it come from? My filter in the user-mgt.xml is without space and the exact same configuration works on a different server)

Especially since it works when I open the user profile:

```
DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Searching for user user@domain.com
DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  value after escaping special characters in user@domain.com : user@domain.com
DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  User: user@domain.com exist: true
DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Searching for user with SearchFilter: (&(objectClass=user)(mail=user@domain.com)) in SearchBase:
DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Requesting attribute :telephoneNumber
DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Requesting attribute :role
DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Requesting attribute :mail
DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Requesting attribute :givenName
DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Requesting attribute :mobile
DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Requesting attribute :profileConfiguration
DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Requesting attribute :company
DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Requesting attribute :sn
DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Requesting attribute :cn
DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Requesting attribute :co
```

It also works on my second test IS. However there is one difference in the test IS which is not done on my main IS during login:

```
DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  value after escaping special characters in user@domain.com : user@domain.com
```

How can I fix this missing step?

**UPDATE 3:**
I just found a similar issue now, but still couldn't find a solution: [Trailing spaces when authenticating to WSO2 Identity Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39181691/trailing-spaces-when-authenticating-to-wso2-identity-server)

Thank you! 
Mat

Comment: Few things we could check. Is the email address of the user you are trying to login filled in the user profile? What is the mapped attribute of emailaddress claim? Can you post a screenshot of the claim config of the service provider?

Comment: Hi @farasath.
The emailaddress is mapped to mail and shown correctly in the user profile within the IS. So I think that should be correct.

I tried different claim configs (Custom and local in the service provider) both get the same error.
This log entry was created while trying with "Use Local Claim Dialect" and only http://wso2.org/claims/emailaddress as claim and subject. 
Or do you mean the claim configuration for the user store?

Comment: I noticed the username is user@domain.com, is this an email username or the domain.com part is the tenant domain?

Comment: Hi @farasath. It is an email username. We do not currently work with tenants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello fellow IS Users,

so after seeing the report on  [Trailing spaces when authenticating to WSO2 Identity Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39181691/trailing-spaces-when-authenticating-to-wso2-identity-server) I checked my saved passwords for the test users.

Unfortunately I had a trailing whitespace in the saved login. Coupled with the bug, this leads to this strange behavior (especially if you type in the login credentials on your test servers).

So this is about 75% my user error and about 25% an IS bug.

I will have a look if there is already a bug issue in the wso2 jira, otherwise I'll file a bug report.

UPDATE: Filed Bug: https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-5864

Cheers Mat